# Shearing in Babylon.JS

Tags: javascript, graphics, transform, babylonjs

I was wondering if it is possible to shear a mesh in Babylon.JS?

I know in Three.Js you can apply a shear matrix to a mesh to shear it.

for example, shearing a cube in Three.JS

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );

var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

matrix.set(   1,   Syx,  Szx,  0,
            Sxy,     1,  Szy,  0,
            Sxz,   Syz,   1,   0,
              0,     0,   0,   1  );

geometry.applyMatrix( matrix );
```

Is this possible to do in Babylon.Js?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answered on Babylon.js forum: https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/shearing-a-mesh/6014